# How can have multiple Modules without repeat injections

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I have 2 applications **`app1`** & **`app2`**

**app1.js**

```
var app = angular.module("app1", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider.when('/view3', {
    templateUrl: 'http://localhost:40/partials/partial3.html',
    controller: 'MyCtrl1 as self'
   });

   $routeProvider.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/view3'
   });
}]);
```

> `app1` has `ngRoute` module, and route config

**app2.js**

```
var app = angular.module("app2", ["app1"]);
```

> `app2` has `app1` module

---

**Note:** `app1` run in `localhost:40` & `app2` in `localhost:50`.

**Question is:** How can use `app1` route configs without inject `ngRoute` in `app2`?

> **i run `app2` with `requirejs` & it works if i inject `ngRoute` in `app2`.**

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. app2 will work if app1 and angular-route *files* are loaded. Having app1 as the dependency in `angular.module("app2", ["app1"])` is enough. The term 'injection' is used incorrectly here and doesn't really help to understand what you're trying to do.