# How can inject module and source file in same time?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

We have 2 application `app1` & `app2`

**app1.js**

```
var app1 = angular.module("app1", []);
```

**app2.js**

```
var app2 = angular.module("app2", []);
```

**app2/index.html**

```
<div ng-app="app2">

<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="app1.js"></script>
<script src="app2.js"></script>
</div>
```

**Target is** inject `app1` in `app2`

we can do it by add `app2.requires.push('app1');` in `app2.js` and put `<script src="app1.js"></script>` file in `app2/index.html`.

**Question is**

How i can, inject the module and the source file together in same time in `app2`?.

**it's possible?**

Comment: Obviously, with `<script src="app2.js"></script> <script>angular.module("app2").requires.push('app1')</script> <script src="app1.js"></script>`. What is the problem you're trying to solve? You haven't explained that in previous question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48050001/how-can-have-multiple-modules-without-repeat-injections . If `app2` depends on `app1` but doesn't list it as a dependency, this is a mistake that should be fixed in the module itself. Again, this is NOT dependency injection.

Comment: @estus, hi my old friend (tnx for your attention) :), i will answer my past question, but this question completely different with that. in this question i want to inject module and file together. for example when `app2` run, then `app1.js` file run after it `app1` inject to `app2`.

Comment: i try gulp-inject but for some reasons i couldn't use it

Comment: You likely have XY problem that should be addressed in another way. `requires` is undocumented and its use usually means that something is wrong with design. Is there a specific reason why you didn't do `angular.module("app2", ["app1"])`?

Comment: In fact we have nested applications [20], and i want to handle it without repeat source in each `html` file.

Comment: @estus I don't know maybe you are right and my question is wrong, if you want i can remove it

Comment: Then app2 module should define its dependency on app1 module explicitly, like `angular.module("app2", ["app1"])`. As for app files, their loading process is another task. If you don't like loading app1.js and app2.js in html separately, consider bundling them to single file, either with Gulp concatenation or JS modules. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770413/webpack-2-and-angular-1-exporting-and-import-modules/43858286#43858286) for CommonJS modules (supposed be bundled with Browserify or Webpack).